# Having an issue with a IF command in visual studio

Tags: c#, if-statement

Beginner in programming and our text uses pseudo code only which makes converting it into c# a giant pain. Specifically i'm having an issue with the console program crashing when it comes to this

```
class Program
    {           const int pkgprice = 99;// Software package price
        int SFTWR = 0;// number of software packages purchased
        int Total = 0;// Total price of sale after discounts applied

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int SFTWR = 0;// number of software packages purchased
            int Total = 0;// Total price of sale after discounts applied

            {//software packages purchased
                Console.WriteLine("How many software packages are you purchasing?");

                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out SFTWR) || SFTWR <= 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("INVALID PLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER");

            }//end software packages purchased

            if (SFTWR <= 9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your total is ${}. No discounts were applied due the low volume of the order", Total = SFTWR * pkgprice);
            }
```

I noticed that it crashes when the variable math problem is in the command. Am I supposed to reference something and if so how?

Comment: Define "crashes". This is rarely an adequate explanation.

Comment: One thing I see: I think that ${} should be ${0}. But I don't know if that is the cause of your crash.

Comment: *"our text uses pseudo code only which makes converting it into c# a giant pain"*. You need to understand the pseudocode before trying to write it in C# (or whatever language you are using). This is a skill that you will use in the software development industry, so now would be a good time to get used to it.

Comment: Just want to mention, if your goal is to do this professionally one day, if you find it a "giant pain" to convert pseudo code to C#, remember that when you do this for a job, you're given vague English descriptions of what people want and you must turn that into C#. Reading pseudocode is a skill you will need to be a developer so don't look at it as a pain, look at it as a challenge to master.

Comment: i understand the pseudo code but our instructor has us writing in C# without a good reference to follow other than what he shows us in visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use global `SFTWR` and `Total`, you must make your variable `static` to use int `Main()`:

```
class Program
    {
        const int pkgprice = 99;   // Software package price
        static int SFTWR = 0;      // number of software packages purchased
        static int Total = 0;      // Total price of sale after discounts applied
```

And change this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your total is ${}. No discounts were applied due the low volume of the order", Total = SFTWR * pkgprice);
```

To

```
Console.WriteLine("Your total is ${0}. No discounts were applied due the low volume of the order", Total = SFTWR * pkgprice);
```

Note: `{}` is wrong format, use `{0}` which stand for first variable after this format string.

The completed code look like this:

```
public static partial class Program
{
    const int pkgprice = 99;   // Software package price
    static int SFTWR = 0;      // number of software packages purchased
    static int Total = 0;      // Total price of sale after discounts applied

    static void Main()
    {
        {//software packages purchased
            Console.WriteLine("How many software packages are you purchasing?");

            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out SFTWR) || SFTWR <= 0)
                Console.WriteLine("INVALID PLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER");

        }//end software packages purchased

        if (SFTWR <= 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your total is ${0}. No discounts were applied due the low volume of the order", Total = SFTWR * pkgprice);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also he needs to remove the method-local SFTWR and Total. Or keep those and remove the class-wide ones.

Comment: @NexTerren Correct. Good catch :)

Comment: I think he wants it to print a $ as well as the number